# series.where on a series containing lists

Tags: pandas, series

I have this series called `hours_by_analysis_date`, where the index is `datetime`s, and the values are a list of ints. For example:

```
Index      |
01-01-2000 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
01-02-2000 | [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
01-03-2000 | [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to return all the indices where the value is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, so it should return `01-01-2000` and `01-03-2000`

I tried `hours_by_analysis_date.where(fh_by_analysis_date==[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, but it gives me the error:

`{ValueError} lengths must match to compare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's confused between comparing two array-like objects and equality test for each element.

You can use `apply`:

```
hours_by_analysis_date.apply(lambda elem: elem == [1,2,3,4,5])
```